# Android 7 + - Stack #0 vs Stack #1

Tags: android, stack, adb, android-task, dumpsys

I wanted to resolve some multi-activity issues in android and someone pointed to me a command to analyze the currently active activities using :
`adb shell dumpsys activity activities` 
From what I understand, Nougat has 2 stacks : `Stack #0` and `Stack #1`. Stack 0 is a launcher stack and Stack 1 is a more generic stack. This was done to facilitate multitasking. Can someone elaborate more on the difference and use-cases of these stacks? 
I have a situation as follows :
An activity `Activity A` (in app A) is present is the `Stack #0`. This launches an `Activity B` (in app B)(using `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`) which is launched in `Stack #1`. Now I am sending an intent for `Activity A` and I expect this intent to just resume the instance already present in `Stack #0` but this is not the case. This intent causes a new instance of `Activity A` to be created in `Stack #1`.

How can I obtain my desired behavior ?